# why does this progressive jpeg not load progressively?

Tags: jpeg, progressive-download

I have some large images on my web site, and so I saved them as progressive jpegs. That way the user should see that something is happening while they download. But nothing shows up for several seconds until the entire jpeg is downloaded. What am I doing wrong?

The site (the large image should be obvious)
http://www.heylookthatsme.com

A typical image on its own, displaying properly:
http://www.heylookthatsme.com/art/stories/Wonderland.jpg

EDIT: it look like it may be due to my using tables for layout. A bit of Googling suggests that tables won't show anything until the last byte is downloaded. I'll try using pure DIVs and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can be perfectly correct in your progressive jpegs but the web browser does not have to display them frame-by-frame.

The display of the image is entirely up to the decoder. It's more complicated to implement, say, a web browser that continuously updates a progressive JPEG than to buffer it and display it all at once.

Remember, each browser can do it differently.

Comment: Thanks. I'm finding that is true. After some experiments, I had to change two things: remove the tables, and also ensure there was no previous image in place. I was using javascript to change the "src" variable of an img. If I replaced an image with another image then progression was ignored. But if I replaced the image with nothing (img ="") and added a timer to then load the new image a split second later, then success: the new image loads progressively. I can't find any other reference to this problem online, so hopefully this info will be of use to somebody.

Comment: Your use of progressive jpeg may not be in vain. Often, progressive jpegs are smaller than sequential.