# Progressive JPEG not loaded in an expected way

Tags: html, reactjs, jpeg

I saw many discussions that mentioned **Progressive jpeg** can enable progressive loading of image:

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/what-is-a-progressive-jpeg/

However, I failed to get this effect after I converted my images to progressive ones using the following shell script (on Mac):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Change to the directory containing the images
cd /path/to/images

# Loop through all the .jpg files in the directory
for file in *.jpg; do
    # Check if the file is a regular file
    if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
        # Create a temporary file name
        temp_file="${file%.jpg}_temp.jpg"
        
        # Transform the image to progressive JPEG using jpegtran
        jpegtran -progressive -copy none -outfile "$temp_file" "$file"
        
        # Replace the original file with the progressive JPEG
        mv "$temp_file" "$file"
        
        echo "Converted $file to progressive JPEG."
    fi
done

echo "All .jpg files converted to progressive JPEG."
```

I ran web page test and other online image test to confirm that the converted ones are recognized as the progressive ones.

To simplify the question, I made a demo for this question ([CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-engelbart-4g78qd?file=/src/App.js))
In this app, I imported two versions of the big earth photos from [wiki](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Full_Disk_Image_of_Earth_Captured_August_24%2C_2011_%286076923014%29.jpg), and you can observe the loading effects when you throttle the network in browser developer tools to slower options.

In this react webpage, I cannot tell the difference of loading the ordinary one or the progressive one. They were both loaded from top to the bottom.

I read the old article about this issue, [why does this progressive jpeg not load progressively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228631/why-does-this-progressive-jpeg-not-load-progressively) but now it's 2023 I would expect better support from the browser.

Hence, I wonder what's wrong with my usage of the progressive jpeg?
Or, it is still not supported in current browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested in Chrome, the progressive one does render a lot faster (both images have the same size)

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bouman-z6mvsk?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ width: "100%", margin: "0 auto", display: "flex" }}>
        not progressive:
        <img
          style={{ width: "300px" }}
          src="https://i.imgur.com/XnxTzbu.jpeg"
          alt=""
        />
        progressive:
        <img
          style={{ width: "300px" }}
          src="https://i.imgur.com/OnoYz3S.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow, you proved that my working was not totally in vain, but I was actually want to see this:

For progressive JPEG, the image appears all at once as a whole, but it’ll be blurry and pixelated at first. Gradually, you will see a clear and fully loaded image.

Comment: Yeah... just tested in Firefox and got the same behaviour, 2023 is not yet the year to have full support on this